# Showing tag badges in "about me" section

Tags: support, profile-page, tag-badges

I'd like to put a [tag badge] with link (like picture shown)  in my "About Me" section. How can I do so?

Is there a way to list all my tag badges using code?

[image]

Comment: You can't use javascript in your profile page.

Comment: I mean, the "Top Tags" section is directly below the About Me section, so it's not that far...?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it is only showing 6 tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to render badges in your profile text and we currently [have no plans to add the feature to Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286368).

You'll have to stick to just standard links if you want them to appear in your profile, or inserting images of the badges (though you'll quickly run out of characters by inserting a bunch of images).